# Zend framework identical validator does not work with annotations

Tags: validation, annotations, zend-framework2

I'm trying to validate a password confirmation field from another password field using zend validator Identical.
I use annotations to declare validators in my entity class. But it doesn't seem to work...

```
   /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable = false)
   * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"password", "class":"form-control","name":"mypass"})
   * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Password"})
   * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim", "name":"StripTags"})
   */

   protected $password;  

   /**
   * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"password", "class":"form-control","id":"password_confirm"})
   * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Confirmation"})
   * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Identical", "options":{"token" : "mypass"}})
   * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim", "name":"StripTags"})
   */

   protected $password_confirm;
```

Can' you tell me what's wrong in my declaration ?

Comment: Why are you storing the password confirmation field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set `strict` to `false` if you want to compare with an element. Otherwise it will just validate it against the `string` value of "mypass" instead of the `object` named "mypass".

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Confirmation"})
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Identical", "options":{"strict": false, "token" : "mypass"}})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim", "name":"StripTags"})
 */
protected $password_confirm;
```

Comment: Thanks you very work it works fine now ! and I don't need to set the name attribute of the first field, it's the name of the variable.